# Connection timeout for Windows Live Messenger using smack

Tags: java, xmpp, smack, windows-live-messenger

I am trying to connect to Windows Live Messenger using Smack, using the sample code available at https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK. Unfortunately, using the exact same code gives me a connection timeout:

`XMPPError connecting to messenger.live.com:5222.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to messenger.live.com:5222`

Did anybody managed to connect using the library? maybe there's a mistake there. FYI, I got the access token correctly, authorised the app before trying to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well I was actually missing the wl.messenger scope for the token, that's all!